# which value does the javascript array.indexOf take as index position

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following array, which value is considered as the fourth index/position by javascript, in `indexOf()` method. Is it `"Mango"` or `"Banana"` ?

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple", 4);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: banana would be

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little tool to play with:

```js
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]
var index = parseInt(prompt("Give an integer between 0 and " + (arr.length - 1)));
alert("At index: " + index + " we find: " + arr[index]);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, ":", arr[i]);
}
```